# Power bank's output current

Tags: power-supply, current, voltage-regulator, powerbanks

I'm wondering what factor determines the maximum output current of a power bank. Is it limited by the internal battery's current or the output current of the voltage regulator? Also I'm not sure that all of the power banks have a voltage regulator for their output. The maximum output current of the [typical power banks](https://ie.rs-online.com/web/p/power-banks/2019785/) is around 2.5A but it can goes up to [4.8A](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32802590990.html).

Comment: For both, Internal resistance -> heat or voltage drop. Weakest link.

Comment: The maximum output current is determined by the designer and that person picks the appropriate parts to accomplish his requirements. You are probably correct I would also assume all do not have a regulator. From your links this difference is easy to see. You will have to research each power bank you are interested in, there is no set of rules they follow.

Comment: @DKNguyen Do you mean both of them could be the limiting factors?

Comment: @Gil Thanks. Do you know any specific reference which shows the calculation for the maximum output current of a power bank?

Comment: Internal resistance causes both heat and voltage drop. One of the two will become a problem first depending on system details.

Comment: That would have to come from the manufacturer of the power bank. You can disassemble one, reverse engineer it and then do the calculations or you can test the capacity if your interested.